# How can I navigate to another page on image click in .NET MAUI mobile app?

Tags: mobile, maui

I want to navigate to another page when an image is clicked in a .NET MAUI application.

This is the code in .xaml file.

```xml
<Frame
    CornerRadius="100"
    HeightRequest="60"
    WidthRequest="60"
    Padding="0"
    Margin="5"
    BorderColor="#33cccc"
    >
    <Image Source="icon_notes.png"
        Aspect="AspectFill"
        HeightRequest="60"
        WidthRequest="60">
        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer 
                Tapped="OnImage1Tapped"/>
        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>
</Frame>
```

And this is the code in *.xaml.cs*  file.

```cs
private async void OnImage1Tapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
{
    await DisplayAlert("OK", "OK", "OK");

    var next =new DisplayImage();

    await Navigation.PushAsync(next);
}
```

This is the *DisplayImage.xaml* file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="StudyTips.Views.DisplayImage"
             Title="NewPage1"> 
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

For testing I added `DisplayAlert()` and it works, but the Navigation doesn't.
Any help would be appreciated a lot.

Comment: is the first page contained in a `NaviationPage`?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/navigationpage

Comment: Search `net maui shell navigation`.

Comment: Are you using Shell? What's the `MainPage` set to?